# How to put JLabel on my current code? I'm working on POS type of school project

Tags: java, swing

Here's my current code, tried to add JLabel on public Pos but it won't show up and I don't have any error when I did that. How do I add JLabel on my project? I'm a beginner and I don't know if I have to put something else just so my JLabel would show up.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Pos extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JMenuBar mainBar = new JMenuBar();
    private JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("File");
    private JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    private JLabel itemLabel = new JLabel("Item Name:");


    public Pos() {

        setTitle("Point of Sale System");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setJMenuBar(mainBar);
        mainBar.add(menu1);
        menu1.add(exit);
        exit.addActionListener(this);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Object source = e.getSource();
        Container con = getContentPane();
        if(source == exit)
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Pos mFrame = new Pos();
        final int WIDTH = 500;
        final int HEIGHT = 700;
        mFrame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        mFrame.setVisible(true);
        mFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try using `add(itemLabel);` as the last line your constructor?

Comment: MadProgrammer thanks it works now, now my remaining problem is placing. Thanks again

Comment: Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: thank you for this MadProgrammer

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding the label to the frame, it's only declared as a member variable. In the Pos constructor, add:

```
this.add(itemLabel);
```

Answer (score 0):

On a Frame you need to use getContentPane(). The way you are doing it is OK for a JPanel but not for a JDialog or JFrame (and you have to actually do the add). Like this:

```
public Pos() {

    setTitle("Point of Sale System");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout()); // <--
    getContentPane().add(itemLabel); // <--
    setJMenuBar(mainBar);
    mainBar.add(menu1);
    menu1.add(exit);
    exit.addActionListener(this);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add as below:

```
public Pos() {

        setTitle("Point of Sale System");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setJMenuBar(mainBar);
        mainBar.add(menu1);
        menu1.add(exit);
        exit.addActionListener(this);
        add(itemLabel);

    }
```